# Edited IpTables, now SFTP suddenly stopped working

Tags: iptables, centos6

I removed some things from my IPTables that were no longer needed and now my SFTP simply times out upon attempting to connect with FileZilla:

```
Status: Connecting to ###.93.110.###...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=3
Command:    open "root@###.93.110.###" 22
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

IPTables:

```
iptables -L -n --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5431
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25565
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443
8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25999
10   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4000
11   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4001
12   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4005
13   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:115
14   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

You're allowing port 22 (SSH) in three places, lines 1, 8 and 14.

Port 22 is the correct port, is the SSH/SCP service running?  Do you get a response when you "telnet ###.93.110.### 22"?